# mac OS using MediaLibrary - how to define which Photos Library is loaded?

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-sierra

I'm sure this is right in front of my face, but I'm a bit of a nooob...

How can I define which Photos Library is loaded vs the current method which loads the System Library?

I presume it's somewhere along the lines of here from the sample code?

```
    // Setup the media library to load only photos, don't include other source types.
    let options: [String : AnyObject] =
        [MLMediaLoadSourceTypesKey: MLMediaSourceType.image.rawValue as AnyObject,
         MLMediaLoadIncludeSourcesKey: [MLMediaSourcePhotosIdentifier, MLMediaSourceiPhotoIdentifier] as AnyObject]

    // Create our media library instance to get our photo.
    mediaLibrary = MLMediaLibrary(options: options)
```

Is it a matter of having selected MLMediaSourceiPhotoIdentifier which defaults to the System Library? If so how do you go about opening other Libraries?

Help! Thankssss

Answer (score 3):

Per the documentation of `MLMediaLibrary`, there is only three other options except for the standard media sources:

Non-App-Specific Media Source Identifiers:

`MLMediaSourceCustomFoldersIdentifier`

*The media source for custom folders. Currently, the only custom folder is the folder containing audio loops from Apple.*

`MLMediaSourceAppDefinedFoldersIdentifier`

*The media source for app-defined folders. This identifies a media source created from a relative path inside the caller’s app bundle.*

`MLMediaSourceMoviesFolderIdentifier`

*The media source for the user’s Movies folder.*

Based on this, I'd say it's highly likely that the functionality to create a `MLMediaLibrary` from an arbitrary filePath does not exist. Indeed, the API will only allow you to interface to the library that is currently being used by iPhoto, iMovie or other apps respectively.

Comment: Oskar, I guess the key question in relation to how to open other libraries then comes down to progamtically setting the System Library.  I have had difficulties in finding this information, is this something you possibly could provide some guidance on? Appreciate your help.

Comment: It cannot be set programmatically. Possible editable through a .plist, but it would certainly require admin privileges, and any mistake could corrupt your Photos setup.

Comment: Oskar do you have any idea where this plist might hide? I noted that the iPhotos plist used to have what appears to be a file path to a library, but this is non-existent in the Photos plist I've been able to locate.  There has to be a way to open other libraries with these Classes!